# Actions with validation

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

It's good that react admin provide actions for us to use in edit/create page. However, the simple form is the child component so the action is without control to the simple form. If I want to validate form data before using fetch to send to the server, how do I trigger the validation?
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Actions.md

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one more class handler and in that pass record and there you can return errors or true in no error case then then you can call fetch.

```
// in src/comments/ApproveButton.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FlatButton from '@material-ui/core/FlatButton';
import { showNotification } from 'react-admin';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
    class ApproveButton extends Component {
        handleValidate(data) {
            const op = // validation logic goes here
            return op;
        }
        handleClick = () => {
            const { push, record, showNotification } = this.props;
            const errors = handleValidate(record);
            if(errors) {
                // show errors in form
                return;
            }
            const updatedRecord = { ...record, is_approved: true };
            fetch(`/comments/${record.id}`, { method: 'PUT', body: updatedRecord })
                .then(() => {
                    showNotification('Comment approved');
                    push('/comments');
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.error(e);
                    showNotification('Error: comment not approved', 'warning')
                });
        }



render() {
        return <FlatButton label="Approve" onClick={this.handleClick} />;
    }
}

ApproveButton.propTypes = {
    push: PropTypes.func,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    showNotification: PropTypes.func,
};

export default connect(null, {
    showNotification,
    push,
})(ApproveButton);
```

Comment: Although I'm hoping to use simpleForm for validation. But this works also. Thanks!